# jQuery child of a parent selection with id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my form,

```
<form action="" method="post" id="signupform">
    <input class="email" id="email"  type="email" placeholder="somebody@example.com" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here's javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#signupform').submit(function(){
         return valid_email();
});
});



function valid_email(){
    var email = $('#signupform > #email ').val();
    alert(email);
    return false;
}
```

It, alerts "Undefined" but, if I use, only `$('#email')`, I get correct value. Where I am making the mistake.

Comment: It works fine here, here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/plsoft/V89AL/)

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, there is also no need for the `#signupform >` so use `var email = $('#email').val();`

Comment: Actually, i do also have an #email ID, inside a form with id #login.
So, i had the plan to get signup's email by #signup > #email
and the login's email by #login >#emai .

Answer (score 1):

Assign initial value to the textbox then you will be able to get it the placeholder is not taken by val() and show empty.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/V89AL/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signupform').submit(function() {
        return valid_email();
    });
});

function valid_email() {
    var email = $('#signupform > #email ').val();
    alert(email);
    return false;
}​
```